# WPF application resolution & layout problem

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF project and the main window size is: `Height="672.4" Width="1458"`. when I run the app it is ok & everything looks right, but when I run the same app on the other PC, The location of controls and their layout collapses!

> the resolution of the first PC is 1536 x 864 and the second one is 1366 x 768!

What should I do to make the layout of all controls the same in any resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Not Use Height And Weight for fix size in WPF XAML Page i refer this :

```
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Create one grid on xaml page :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="#FFF1F1F1">
          .............YOUR_CODE...........
 </Grid>
```

Comment: What does it do? Can you please explain?

Comment: yaa no problem!! i will try to explain you!! same as web design, for this Grid.ColumnDefinitions and Grid.RowDefinitions for responsive design right, we never fixed to height and weight for our wpf window or usercontrol at that time we use this!! i think you are new to this so i will provide you refrence link please refer it and than try to apply in your code. it surely help you to solve your problme.   https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/grid-layout-in-wpf/